# laravel 5.5 not support jwt auth lib

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, jwt

I am new in Laravel and using JWT auth in laravel 5.5.18 but its not working for me its give error in api login 
`Interface 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject' not found"`

Can any one help me how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: I have checked in google its suggest me to update the jwt lib but its also not working when I used composer update its hang ....

Comment: what is the version of `tymondesigns/jwt-auth`?

Comment: "tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-beta.3@dev"

Comment: make sure you've got <project>/vendor/tymon/src/...  and then also run composer dump-auto - just to make sure you've got the files and they are autoloading.

Comment: @TarekAdam yes I have all requires files

Comment: you can use tha ```laravel/passport``` and to remove the package from tha app ```composer remove vendor/package```

Answer (score 8):

Updated Article and Source Code - [www.ultimateakash.com](https://www.ultimateakash.com/blog-details/IixDMGAKYAo=/How-to-Implement-JWT-Authentication-in-Laravel-2021)

```php
composer remove tymon/jwt-auth
composer dump-autoload
```

then install

```php
composer require tymon/jwt-auth:dev-develop --prefer-source
```

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

```php
php artisan jwt:secret
```

```php
Route::post('login', 'ApiController@login');
Route::post('register', 'ApiController@register');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth.jwt'], function () {
    Route::get('logout', 'ApiController@logout');
    Route::get('user', 'ApiController@getAuthUser');

});
```

```php
?php
 
namespace App;
 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
 
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;
 
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
 
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
 
    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
 
    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
 
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();
 
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $user
        ], 200);
    }
 
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $jwt_token = null;
 
        if (!$jwt_token = JWTAuth::attempt($input)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
            ], 401);
        }
 
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $jwt_token,
        ]);
    }
 
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required'
        ]);
 
        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate($request->token);
 
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User logged out successfully'
            ]);
        } catch (JWTException $exception) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Sorry, the user cannot be logged out'
            ], 500);
        }
    }
 
    public function getAuthUser(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required'
        ]);
 
        $user = JWTAuth::authenticate($request->token);
 
        return response()->json(['user' => $user]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have follow all these steps and got the lib in vendor folder, set the  key but still its give me  Interface 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject' not found" error so I need to delete old one and start again same process
How to I delete its have any command or just do manually or used direct composer command please suggest me

Comment: use   composer remove tymon/jwt-auth

Comment: Thank you so much. It not for your post here I was going to literally give up on using Laravel. Also a good working example using Laravel 5.7 is here - https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-jwt/

Answer (score 0):

You may considerate to use **Laravel Passport**

**From the laravel official docs:** https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport

> Laravel makes API authentication a breeze using Laravel Passport, which provides a full OAuth2 server implementation for your Laravel application in a matter of minutes. Passport is built on top of the League OAuth2 server that is maintained by Andy Millington and Simon Hamp.

Indeed since the library is maintained by the creator of Laravel, it will be more up-to-date and stable for Laravel than other concurrent libraries.